# Speed of numpy array division

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division

I'm processing a lot of 16bit image data and have been trying to figure out more efficient ways to handle it. What I'm doing is loading images and then dividing by a reference "calibration" image (2000-10000 images that are roughly 1024x128 pixels). The (numpy) process goes roughly like this:

1. Load array from image file (cv2)
2. Divide by (2^16 - 1) to get data to be between 0 and 1. This makes it float64
3. Divide array by fixed calibration array (same shape and size). So `arr / cal_array`
4. Perform a couple more operations (using np.average, so pretty quick)
5. Store data into pandas dataframe
6. Play games with analysis and plotting.

In terms of data size, I have no need of anything more than float32, since the very most precision needed is `1/(2^16-1) ~ 1.525e-5` (that is, min size for `arr` / max size for `cal_array` pixel) and float32 gets me down to `2e-38` or something like that, and I fundamentally do not care about the imprecision. (Honestly, I probably don't care about the precision for float16 either).

Questions:

1. For step (3), would it be faster to precompute `cal_inv_array = 1/cal_array`? So instead of doing a ton of `arr_i / cal_array`, instead doing it as `arr_i * cal_inv_array`.
2. For step (3 and 4), is it faster to do the divisions/multiplications as `float32` or `float64`? (Windows 64bit machine).
3. Would it be faster still to do that as `float16` and save an extra 1/2 in the memory? Or should I not bother?
4. If I'm working in `float64` should I then convert to `float32` before storing it in the array, or store the whole thing and then do a conversion? (I very much suspect the former).
5. Should I bother with `float16` at all? Would I maybe be losing more precision than I think?

I've been trying to research (1), and it's been surprisingly hard to find information about the speed of array division, where it isn't just `arr / const`. I don't *really* need the speed for this particular work (and using pandarallel has helped me a lot already), but this is as good a time as any to learn.

Edit: I ran benchmarks on the code based on information from @Homer512. In order, the speeds were:

1. Convert to float32 and multiply by inverse
2. Convert to float16 and multiply by inverse
3. int16 / int16 division
4. Treat as float64 and multiply by inverse
5. Treat as float64 and divide by calibration

However, the times for all of these were relatively quick. Now I think that the slow time for the data analysis I've been running is almost certainly memory overload. (When I increased the number of entries from 2000 to 4000, I had a 4-6x slowdown, which is in keeping with the time I've been waiting for data to crunch.) In this way, going to float32 (or float16 if I *have to*) is going to make more difference than any other methodology I could try. I might end up going with the slower, but more legible methods.

Edit: simplified code sample, just showing how the division is invoked.  I'm using list append for simplicity

```
 max_brightness = 2**16 - 1
 cal_arr = cv2.imread(cal_filepath, -1) / max_brightness
 all_data = []

 for filepath in filepaths:
      arr = cv2.imread(filepath, -1) / max_brightness
      arr_calibrated = arr / cal_arr
      
      arr_averaged = np.average(arr_calibrated, axis=0)
      
      all_data.append([arr_calibrated, arr_averaged])
```

Comment: What is your actual code? It can make a big difference how you actually invoke the numpy array division. Also, have you profiled your code? If so, what were the results? Are you sure it is the array division that is slow?

Comment: I haven't profiled the code. I know there are lots of other ways to speed things up, but I'm curious about the theory of division speed, for preparation for if I have to deal with larger images (max size for this camera is roughly 2048x2048).

I've added a code sample for how I'm invoking the division.

Answer (score 1):

> Divide by (2^16 - 1) to get data to be between 0 and 1. This makes it float64

Going to float64 seems unnecessary. Why not go to float32 directly? It can accurately represent all 16 bit integers, at least.

> For step (3), would it be faster to precompute `cal_inv_array = 1/cal_array`? So instead of doing a ton of `arr_i / cal_array`, instead doing it as `arr_i * cal_inv_array`.

Yes. Floating point division is as expensive as computing a square root. In fact, you can combine this step with the division by 2^16-1 that you did in the step before.

```py
scale = (1. / 65535.) / cal_array.astype('f4')
image = image.astype('f4') * scale
```

> For step (3 and 4), is it faster to do the divisions/multiplications as float32 or float64? (Windows 64bit machine).

x86-64 (and other mainstream architectures) have vectorized floating point units of fixed size, e.g. 128 bit for SSE2 that is present in all intel-compatible 64bit CPUs. Those 128 bit can be 2 float64 or 4 float32.

Therefore the throughput on large vectorized array computations is doubled in float32. Likewise, using a type that is twice as large also takes double the memory bandwidth and has a harder time fitting into CPU caches. Therefore float32 is usually a win.

Exceptions may occur. For example `numpy.average` is actually a bit faster when given a float64 array. I assume it works internally in float64 so this saves a conversion. But the difference is small. It may be worth benchmarking your final compute pipeline.

> Would it be faster still to do that as float16 and save an extra 1/2 in the memory? Or should I not bother?

Don't bother. Your system likely has no hardware support for float16. That makes all computations significantly slower. Numpy's support for float16 is more useful to feed the data to a GPU than to compute on it directly.

> If I'm working in float64 should I then convert to float32 before storing it in the array, or store the whole thing and then do a conversion? (I very much suspect the former).

Remember that numpy operations are "eager". Each step does a computation on the entire array. So something like `(image * scale).astype('f4')` first does the computation, dumping the whole result into memory. Then it reads it all again to write it back into memory as float32.

Doing this extra step can only be worth it when you consider the entire computation, for example if it saves time in the next few steps or saves memory overall.

I'm unsure whether you mean saving the results in that list at the very end. If you mean that, then yes, saving main memory may be helpful in the long run. Even just by allocating less memory from the OS, this may already speed up the computation.

> I've been trying to research (1), and it's been surprisingly hard to find information about the speed of array division, where it isn't just arr / const.

If you want to learn more about the internals of a CPU, I recommend [Agner's resources](https://www.agner.org/optimize/). They are targeted at C++ developers so you can skip large sections but it still gives a lot of insight.

Comment: This is fantastic and thorough, thank you! One reason I didn't think of doing that with the `cal_array` was because the calibration array itself is (vaguely) useful as an image, but `1/array` doesn't mean much. From what you've said, for the most part, I'm probably going to want to convert my data to `float32` , but I'll have to run a few tests. I'm also guessing that a non-trivial amount of the time is devoted to the io part, although I sped that bit up by a solid amount by moving from PIL to cv2.